# Cannot delete a player object after checking for a `created_by` attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I have a DELETE operation as part of a NodeJS API I have built. This delete should do the following:

- Delete a player object with the ID provided
- It should not delete a player created by another user.

In the tests it passes if the player is created by another user but fails when it attempts to delete the object. Here is the code:

```
router.delete('/:id', validateBearerToken, function(req, res) {
  let playerId = req.params.id;
  //get player object
  let player = Player.find({created_by: playerId
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) return res.status(409).send('There was a problem finding the players.');
  });

  if (player.created_by !== getUserFromBearerToken(req.token)) {
    return res.status(404).send('The player not created by this user');
  }
  Player.findByIdAndRemove(playerId, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(404).send('There was a problem deleting the player.');
    }
    res.status(200).send({
      success: true
    });
  });
});
```

validateBearerToken is used to check if the user executing the delete operation is valid

```
function validateBearerToken(req, res, next) {
  let bearerToken;
  let bearerHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
    let bearer = bearerHeader.split('Bearer ');
    bearerToken = bearer[1];
    req.token = bearerToken;
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(403).send();
  }
}
```

gertUserFromBearerToken is used to get the id of the logged in user to compare with the 'created_by` id in the test:

```
function getUserFromBearerToken(token) {
  const decodedtoken = jwt.decode(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  return decodedtoken.id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you verification middle-ware (`validateBearerToken`) should be like this

```
function validateBearerToken(req, res, next) {
  var token = req.headers.authorization || req.headers['x-access-token'];
  if (!token)
    return res.status(403).send({ auth: false, message: 'No token provided.' });
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, function(err, decoded) {
    if (err)
    return res.status(500).send({ auth: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
    // if everything good, save to request for use in other routes
    req.userId = decoded.id;
    next();
  });
}
```

then in delete route check for id like this

```
if (player.created_by !== req.userId) {
    return res.status(404).send('The player not created by this user');
}
```

Comment: So I guess i don't need the `getUserFromBearerToken` function anymore?

Comment: @ghost_king yes you dont need it now and if my answer helped please mark my answer as approved